# Default time zone in php

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to save the current date and time and i have used the following code

**Current PHP version: 5.4.16**

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
 $datet = date("Y-m-d H:i:s ");
```

When i echo it the output will be

```
2017-04-25 05:07:17
```

But actual time what i need is

```
2017-04-25 10:45:17
```

I have tried using `now()` but its also showing the same date rather than the current time, In what ways i can get the Current date and time. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You above code is working fine., Check for other  errors or share the code you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change the server time, print date on console, if this mismatched, then change the server time.

Answer (score 0):

### Check This

This gives you correct time after setting default time zone "Asia/Kolkata"

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

Comment: Because of Capital h and Double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Please check my attachment. Here, First of all I have check 
echo date_default_timezone_get();` and getting my default timezone **Asia/Calcutta** and after that when I changed timezone  as

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
Asia/Bangkok
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9BW8.png)